# How can I Pause an Activity 'B' while going to Activity 'C'

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing a web application, in this I have 3(A, B and C) classes.  How can I Pause an Activity 'B'(which contain a Specializations list) while going to Activity 'C'(which contain a Doctors list), and again I want to go back to Activity 'B' from Activity 'C',  when I pressed custom back button which is in Activity 'C.'.  And The data which is presented in the Activity 'B' should be available in 'B' Activity, but it is not displaying the values. It is is opening the Activity 'B' with empty screen.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the cycle of Activity from Documentation [Activity Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 1):

when u are going from activity B to another activity C, overridden `onPause()` method of activity is called you need not to call that `onPause()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to move code from activity 'B' `OnCreate()` method to `onResume()` method.